# ELL uses a font that, if installed, renders poorly in Windows

Tags: bug, design

This only really applies to anyone with Windows and Helvetica Neue installed.

ELL, as it is an SE beta site, uses the font Helvetica Neue. This looks bad in Windows:
[image: poorly rendered words]

Comment: I don't really expect this to be changed, but I didn't know how else to tag.

Comment: Here's how it looks for me in Chrome on Linux: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CB5DW.png

Comment: @snailboat: It looks like you don't have Helvetica Neue installed. The next font in the list is Arial, and then if you don't have that you see generic sans-serif. ("font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Arial,sans-serif;")

Answer (score 2):

I installed Helvetica Neue today in order to make my Halloween costume (Cards Against Humanity card), noticed the bad rendering pictured above, then found [this fix](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/J4dqHZD3dcs), which is working beautifully: 
[image: well rendered words]

I know it probably doesn't affect the vast majority of you, but if I save one person from seeing a poorly rendered font every time they visit, I'll feel warm and fuzzy.

Comment: What happens in your display with characters which Helvetica Neue doesn't possess? --This is not idle curiosity; at some point ELL is going to graduate and have to pick a font, and it would be helpful to know whether that font will accommodate IPA characters, as in the answers [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/3446/32), and glyphs like `&larr;`, `&lowast;` and `&sdot;`.

Comment: @StoneyB It simply drops to the next available font. It's [not pretty](http://static.ow.ly/photos/original/3BcIf.png), but it's not prohibitive.

Comment: Woof! The trans-ASCIIs don't bother me that much; but what on earth is Chrome's problem with the round elements in that poor font?!

Comment: @StoneyB That screenshot was actually taken in IE, so I'm thinking the problem might actually be Windows. I don't know enough about font loading or rendering to know more about what's happening or how common it is. It certainly does look "nibbled on" to me.